# MYSQL select from where except some LINE

Tags: mysql

I have a basic question: how to make a mysql query that query all the table but except line 8 and line 13?

```
select * from table where //BUT VALUE NOT IN LINE 8 AND LINE 13.(ID=8 AND ID=13)



id|name
1 | a
2 | b
3 | c
4 | d
5 | e
6 | f
7 | g
8 | h // except line 8
9 | i
10| j
11| k
12| l
13| m // except line 13
14| n
```

Comment: What do you mean by "line"? Is that the name of a column in the table?

Comment: @Mark Byers, yes, forget explain clearly.

Comment: if your ID is an auto number, it will not always be the case that the ID is equivalent to row number.  Were you aware of this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `NOT IN`:

```
SELECT col1, col2, ..., coln
FROM yourtable
WHERE id NOT IN (8, 13)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from table where 
id !=8 AND id != 13
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that "LINE 8" and "LINE 13" correspond to primary key values, your query would look like this:

`SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE ID NOT IN (8,13)`

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID <> 1
```

<> is "not equals" in mysql.

Goodluck.